# With Obj-C Realm, is there any way to use NSNumber<RLMInt> from Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, realm

We are currently using Objc Realm 0.96 with Swift (because our app supports also iOS7) and looking for a way to have nullable Int as one of the properties of `RLMObject` subclass. According to the Official document, `NSNumber<RLMInt>` should be used for that purpose but it seems like tagging `NSNumber` with specific type is not supported on Swift side unfortunately.

Does anyone have any idea how to support nullable Int or Bool from Swift side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a limitation with Swift. Currently the only way is to either define the model in Objective-C or declare the type as `NSNumber` and set a default value, which allows Swift to determine the boxed type at runtime. This default value must be different from `nil`.

Comment: I see... I will consider using a default number. Thank you vm for your answer!

Comment: marius I have problem with this error in objective c

Comment: @user3182143: It's not clear to me what error you're referring to. As this question is about Swift, could you open a new question and elaborate your problem there?

Comment: @user3182143: Could you open a new question and elaborate your problem there with the exception message?

Answer (score 0):

With current Swift language feature, we can now do this to have `nil` as default value for optional Int or Bool in Swift with Realm-Objc

Optional Bool:
`dynamic var optionalBool: (NSNumber & RLMBool)?`

Optional Int:
`dynamic var optionalInt: (NSNumber & RLMInt)?`